# How To Export Blender Mesh w/ Shaders to Unity

Tags: mesh, export, shaders, unity

I am following CG Geek's [How to Create a Low Poly Tree in 1 Minute](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7PdiGXbrD0&t=52s) and I want to export this tree, shaders and all, to Unity so I can add it to my game. How would someone go about exporting a (Cycles Rendered) mesh To Unity? Thank You In advance!

***(BTW, I know there are a lot of people that already asked this but I tried them and they don't work. Also (I think), my circumstance is kind of specific)***

Comment: Related: [How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake)

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** use Blender cycles shaders in unity. Unity has its own nodes, you need to bake out the cycles rendered texture on the model in the scene, and then export them with the FBX exporter addon.

Comment: thanks! But how would I go about that (sorry I'm a beginner )?