# How to export materials from blender to unity

Tags: export, shaders, unity

Does anyone know how to export shaders or materials from Blender to Unity?
Any help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Sadly the Blender shaders are incompatible to directly be transferred into Unity, you would have to create your own node setup with the Unity shader node editor.

Comment: Another way you can do this is to bake your materials into image textures and then use them in Unity.

Comment: Can I don't ssave the materials as a .mat file or give it a mod to do this?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541