# Can blender materials become textures?

Tags: texturing, materials, export

I know that you can't export blender models with their materials. Is there any way I may be able to turn the materials into a texture which I can export separately?

Thanks, I'm quite new and I just need a solution to this problem.

Comment: Yup. That's [Baking](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/baking.html).

Comment: How would I do that / where can I find a tutorial for it.

Comment: Search: [Texture Baking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=texture+baking) ;)

Comment: Hard to make it an answer because it's such a general technique.. a search on 'Blender Baking' throws up a lot of results, sorry I can't recommend any in particular without watching them all myself!

Comment: there is a big search box at the top of the page, so that you can look for answers to questions that have already been asked and answered.

Comment: Appreciate the help guys. Stay safe.

Comment: @vklidu You're right. That's what happens when I'm too lazy to check it myself... :).

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508

Comment: @Duarte to the rescue :).