# How to share my 3d model made using blender?

Tags: modeling

I have made a 3d model in blender and want to share it with my friend. My friend does not have blender and wants to see the model on his mobile. Is there any function in blender that helps me to make a shareable 3d model with a transparent background?

Comment: You can render it and share the image, or you could make a short animation and share that. To make a transparent background in the render: in the Render Settings under the 'Film' tab tick the box 'Transparent' before rendering.

Comment: Hundreds of possibilities... Can you elaborate on *how* the model needs to be displayed? 2d/3d? One easy way is using sketchfab.com However, I'm not sure whether there is a dedicated app.

Comment: It needs to be displayed in 3d @brockmann

Comment: Yeah sure... No matter how detailed? I suggest add some requirements to your q otherwise it is too broad (IMHO) - Related: [How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload the model to [sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/). The model can then be viewed and rotated as a 3d object with no special software, on a web browser.