# How to export procedural material in gltf/glb format?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, export, gltf

I am playing around procedural rust material in Blender and want to apply the material to my sword model so it looks rusty and old to further export it as glb or gltf
this is my node setup

[image]

The required result that I am looking for

[image]

The resulted gltf export

[image]

I have tried baking the material into a texture file and then exporting still same result.

[image]

Comment: Procedural textures can not be transferred over, you would have to bake them, Does this answer your question? [How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake)

Comment: @brockmann I did try baking the texture but still same results Idk where I am going wrong

Comment: Hard to guess, pretty well explained over there. My bake: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RX8U.png based on the first 3 steps of the linked answer (even if the UV's are not that nice, it bakes perfectly).

Comment: After you've baked you have to change the material to a form the glTF exporter understands that actually uses the baked texture.

Comment: Here's a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNE3z424YpM&list=PLvdhJ__UbhZ6mst0xgd_S3oSmdRcEiKCp&index=6&t=988) that demonstrates baking complex nodes into a texturemap, and then exporting that texturemap to glTF.