# Blender 2.92 Material Overlay Problem

Tags: texturing, node-editor, eevee-render-engine

So I'm trying to use an overlay mix shader to map a skin onto a replica of a car from the video game BeamNG.drive. It doesn't look right, still. As you can see in the comparison, the camo is covering up the grille, which is an effect I don't want. Is there a way to fix this? Below is a download link for the blend and textures, too.
[image: Blender]

[image: Game]

[image]

Download link to the replica's body and textures: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TiFgDiN8jyoRT3zb5lrSkbjOURJLpl8k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You'd have to bake the shader.

Comment: How do I bake it in Eevee?

Comment: Switch over to cycles: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake

Comment: I don't think that will help.

Comment: I think that's the only way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I've noticed that the **pigeon_d** texture has alpha transparency. Is there a way to make the texture fill the alpha portion with the skin? Overlay doesn't seem to be working, it just seems to be tinting the material with red.

Comment: I changed the Overlay shader to Mix, and the camo overlay is going away, but it's still not completely away. I looked closer into **pigeon_d** and found out there's partial alpha transparency in the texture. Can this be fixed (without changing the render engine?)