# How to bake one single mesh in 3 textures for Unity?

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I need to bake different textures for this house (it's a unique mesh) but I don't know how to do that. I need to bake a texture for the floor, one for the walls and one for the ceiling in 3 different files.

Is it possible?
[image]

THIS IS NOT THE SAME QUESTION OF THIS POST ([How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake)) I need to know how to bake a single mesh in multiple file

Comment: You could bake it one by one. Bake the floor, bake the walls and bake the ceiling. The importan thing to remember is to UV Unwrap before so non of the textures interfere with the other two

Comment: to bake one by one i need to select the part i want to bake on UV editing?