# Can I use geometry nodes to scatter points only where the material is white?

Tags: materials, node-editor, geometry, procedural

I have a procedural node based material in blender that produces areas of two colours, black and white.  Can I use geometry nodes to scatter points only where the material is white?  I'm looking to get the effect of weight painting, but using a procedural material.  Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to transfer data from the material to geometry nodes. Currently the data flows only in one way : Geometry Nodes Attributes > Material.

I don't think there is a plan to support this feature in the future.

You can however [bake the textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake) and use the [Attribute Sample Texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_sample_texture.html) node to achieve the result, but you will lose the procedural aspect of the workflow.

You may be able to plug into the data flow if you use [OSL](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/render/shader_nodes/osl.html) but that requires good programming knowledge and restricts rendering to CPU only and Cycles engine only.

Comment: Thanks Gorgious, knowing something isn't possible saves a lot of time