# Can't export to VRM with color ramp

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, export

I've created a VRM file with vroidStudio to make a 3D model and imported it to Blender to change the skin to make it look like a humanoid with tritton skin.

In blender it looks like this:
[image: Blender Model]

But when I export with VRM export add-on it looses all the color ramp modifications. I've read that exporters usually doesn't support other than basic nodes.
Is there a way to export it with the color ramp?

Comment: You are probably in the realm of baking the final texture - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13509/110840 - I can't find one for the new UI, but it may exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing something similar right now but you might need to bake the material (your nodes) to a texture. [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7vdpiPV-3E) explains it well (you can skip the information at the start but it is helpful knowledge). Or just look up a tutorial, there are many great ones out there but the basic idea is:

1. Change to cycles
2. Under the Render tab (in the properties tab, often on the right-hand side)
3. Under Bake, set bake type *Diffuse* and only select the colour under influences (Direct and Indirect should be disabled)
4. In your shader window add a vacant image texture floating unattached.
5. Hit new. Name it. Set texture resolution in height/width (should be 1k by default)
6. In image editor (drag open a new window and select if it's not there) and select the image texture to see the result.
7. Then hot *N* over the window and change colour space in the menu to sRGB
8. Go back to render settings and hit *Bake*
9. Save or discard it in the *N* menu

It could also be the addon. I haven't heard of it but if you send me a link and can confirm if that's most likely your problem or not!

Have a good day :)

Comment: I'm going to try this right now, I appreciate the fast response.
edit: https://github.com/saturday06/VRM_Addon_for_Blender I am using this add-on.
Sorry for the edit, i've hit enter and the comment got published.

Comment: No worries and keep me posted. I'm interested to find out!

Comment: Hi and welcome Connor! Just to let you know: This is no regular forum, rather a Q&A site. Link-only answers are discouraged, if the link goes down so 
does the answer. Please help us making this site a real 
knowledgebase and add all relevant steps to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: The video didn't solve my problem at all, but I've managed to work around it. I just baked the texture as the video tutorial showed but it kept messing with the other ones. So I just made a copy of the .blend and add the baked texture.