# How to import big mesh to Blender from photogrammetry

Tags: mesh, import, photogrammetry

I want to import a mesh into *Blender* that I generated with *Zephyr*, but the mesh files became very large:

- wrl: 7.6GB
- obj: 9.5GB
- ply: 3.0GB

I would like improve the mesh and the texture to make an animation in it afterwards. But when I try to import the mesh it fills my 32GB of RAM, then the 32GB swaps and *Blender* crashes. I would try to increase the SWAP next, but I think that is the wrong approach. So does anyone know how to do this properly?

Here a link to the meshfiles (if someone wants to try).

https://web.tresorit.com/l/bspYt#iMCb_eL6xVWfieYp48z0Hw

Using Blender 2.92.0
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04

Comment: You'd have to retopo the object, bake the textures to the low poly, animate and render - more work than you might think: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuQzPDs99yM and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake

Comment: Thanks for the interesting links! Unfortunately I am not even able to import the mesh in Blender. I could possibly export the mesh objects separately in Zephyr and import them separately in Blender. Also a lot of work.

Comment: In reality capture, there is a "simplify mesh" function to polyreduce the mesh to e.g. 2-5mio before the export (which is usually enough for 99% of what you do). I guess there is the same button in Zephyr as well.

Comment: Hi, you could try a program to reduce vertices and texture resulution before importing into *Blender*.

I have used a good program but rigth now I dont remember its name but if I do I will post it here.

But you could try searching *Google* for programs like that!

Answer (score 1):

So I have tried two solutions:

- If I split the mesh so that I only have 1GB files, I could
  successfully import the Mehses. However, Blender was incredibly slow
  and it's not really possible to work with it. It's a pity, because
  the high resolution looks much more realistic.
- The mesh can also be decimated. Of course, it is then no longer as
  beautiful. But it is now possible to work well with Blender. The
  programme runs fast and clean. Unfortunately, one cannot have it al.Cool thing nevertheless!

Comment from the Zephyr Support (Thanks Cameron):

> I typically keep individual meshes around 1,000,000 polys or lower
> unless there is a specific reason you need a very dense mesh. I'd
> recommend using .OBJ with textured mesh instead of .PLY as they are
> much easier to work with in my experience, and in Blender you can drag
> and drop the texture file onto the model.