Is it possible to "freeze" the reflections/lighting on a metallic model from a single point of view?
Blender beginner here.
I'm trying to use a 3D model with a glossy metallic texture as a painting reference, and I'd like to be able to view the placement of reflections and lighting from different perspectives. But since the positions of the reflections on that model naturally change in accordance with the viewing angle, I can only really reference the model from one point of view.
I'm wondering if it's possible to "freeze" (or maybe project) the reflections/lighting from a particular perspective on the model so that I can turn it in space without them changing.

Like this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/242262/extract-the-current-objects-surface-as-generated-by-blender-so-it-can-be-applied/242283#242283

Yes, actually! Is it possible to do this when there's no environment and the object just has a metallic material with some lights pointed at it?
