# How to export Textures from Blender to Substance painter

Tags: texturing

I got model with textures in Blender. I need to add few decals to that model in Substance Painter, but on that existing textures and send it back to Blender for Rendering. I can't find way because it's always exporting from substance to blender.

Comment: If these are really just textures connected to the principled shader, you do not have to export them. Open up substance, choose metal rough, load the model and drag your textures into the project area. If there is something procedural going on in your materials, you'd have to bake them: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake However, the lazy way would be adding your decals without the textures in substance and combine both worlds (the textures) in blender. Does this help? Otherwise I recommend add more details to your q.

Comment: That Combining sounds interesting. Is that done with shader, or how? Since I want my Decal to be on top of my model, like on substance when you make material and new layer and just paint Decal where you want it to be. I never baked in Blender so I would like to avoid baking :D