# How do you Extract the color from a Blender Model?

Tags: materials

I've tried to look at many tutorials but they don't work or I don't understand
Basically all I know is that is isn't possible to download a png of a material *Preview*
But I don't know anything of blender so I just look up tutorials for what I need specifically which is porting models to another program. I've done that already of porting models I just need to material. I literally have been trying for hours I just want the color or at least how do I export it as a png? I've seen people use Uv Editing (Even though they call it Uv Editor) and there's also baking but none of that works. This probably sounds like a mess already but I just need help on doing this >b
[image: Material Preview]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that seems to be in need of explanation is that Materials and Textures aren’t quite the same.

Image Textures, including those that were originally painted in Blender, can thankfully be exported quite easily:

1. Have the image in question open in Blender’s image editor. You can just use the one in the Texture Paint screen.
2. Go to the image editor’s *Image* menu, and click *Save as.*
3. Enter the required information in the appearing file dialog, and click *Save*.

Materials, however, contain other information, such as how textures are to be used. For example, a black and white texture might not be for color at all, but rather to control how rough the material is in parts. Exporting these in Blender currently is nearly impossible outside of exporting the model as a whole, and different formats will store the materials differently with potential loss of configuration. I would say you should just export the image textures, and then re-set up the material in your target program, or using an in-between editor native to the format.