# Material of 3DModel downloaded from Blenderkit missing after exporting to glb

Tags: materials, export, blenderkit

I'm a beginner doing a simple planter, for which I downloaded a model (a cactus plant with the soil & planter beneath) from Blenderkit addon in Blender 2.93.

Everything just looks good in both material and render views, and materials are visible in render result also. But after Exporting it into gltf(.glb) file the downloaded 3DModel(CACTUS WITH SOIL) doesn't have any material for them and is simply shown in white color, whereas my planter looks absolutely fine

I downloaded a porcelain material for it from the same Blenderkit add-on).

I'm using EEVEE

Also tried changing all the options while exporting to .glb, but nothing helped. Tried opening the glb file in https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/ which showed the same result as my 3D viewer

1. I downloaded it from the Blenderkit which you can see in the image, and later I deleted that pot and placed the plant and soil in my planter.
   [image: my model Rendered view and the downloaded model]
2. This is what it looked like when exported to a .glb file and viewed in a Windows 3DViewier
   [image]

3.Node tree
[image]

Comment: Blender [glTF exporter](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html) has limits on the materials it can export because glTF uses a different material system.  Perhaps you're using an unsupported material as described in [exported materials](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html#exported-materials)?

Comment: I think this should work, because my downloaded material doesn't have a principled BSDF but everything else. right now I can't check, but surely will try n post here. Thank you so much. Is there any way to add Principled BSDF without changing all those nodes?

Comment: I'd have to see a screenshot of the material's node tree, but usually it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thank you so much, I couldn't try yet, we don't have power in Chennai due to floods

Comment: @MartyFouts pls check the node tree screenshot that i have provided above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake)

Comment: Procedural materials generated with these nodes generally cannot be exported to software or formats outside of Blender. You'll need to [bake the nodes to textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake) and [connect them to a Principled BSDF material](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html).