# How to use 3d texture for surface?

Tags: subdivision-surface, nurbs-surface, subsurface-scattering, surface-deform

i have downloaded model from poly haven and this is what i got, does anyone can help me how to turn this into surface? sorry, I'm just a newbie [image]

Comment: [Bake](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/baking.html) it https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with it? That blend file includes four plants in a collection and a UV sphere object with a particle system on it which uses the collection of plants for the display.